# Not crawling the same content twice

Tags: web-crawler

I'm building a small application that will crawl sites where the content is growing (like on stackoverflow) the difference is that the content once created is rarely modified.

Now , in the first pass I crawl all the pages in the site.

But next, the paged content of that site - I don't want to re-crawl all of it , just the latest additions.

So if the site has 500 pages, on the second pass if the site has 501 pages then I would only crawl the first and second pages. Would this be a good way to handle the situation ?

In the end, the crawled content will end up in lucene - creating a custom search engine.

So, I would like to avoid crawling multiple times the same content. Any better ideas ?

**EDIT :**

Let's say the site has a page : Results that will be accessed like so :

Results?page=1 , Results?page=2  ...etc

I guess that keeping a track of how many pages there were at the last crawl and just crawl the difference would be enough. ( maybe using a hash of each result on the page - if I start running into the same hashes - I should stop)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, really.

Comment: If you assume that content will never be modified, how do you expect new crawlable links to appear?

Comment: In addition to what Thomas said, this approach doesn't take in account that content may be changed after insertion. Keeping it here on SO, think of questions with lots of answers where clarifications come in terms of modifications to the original question...

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit, I meant that once a "Result" was added it doesn't change . When I said pages I meant more in the sense of paging some results.

The total number of pages changes once stuff is added but the content of one Result doesn't change usually .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each piece of content is at a unique location, just feed these locations (probably URLs) into a hash field and check for it before "crawling" content. The URL should probably be part of your stored data in Lucene anyway, so this should be easy to accomplish by searching before adding to the index.

Comment: Damn, you're right, I just realized that each result on the page must have a unique url. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to store a hash/fingerprint of the content of each page seen. That way, when you refetch a page, you validate the fingerprint, if it matches, nothing has changed and no parsing is needed, since you already process the page and all links on it.

Comment: But actually fetching the page is probably slower than parsing it and adding it to the index. And you'd need to fetch it to hash it.

Comment: That's the conflict .. unless you fetch it (or ask the server outrigh if it changed), you don't really know if it changed .. how does the OP know the page count has changed? Knowing the page name is not the same as knowing its content.. at least I understood the page was similar to SO, where pages DO change.

Answer (score 1):

Does the site issue effective e-tags for each resource being fetched?  If so you could issue conditional GETs of known resources and in the case that the server sends the resource (i.e. it has changed) you could look for new links to crawl, update the content, etc.

Of course this only works if your site issues E-Tags and responds to the conditional get...

Answer (score 1):

1. do a standard site-wide crawl of the website to get all the historical content
2. track their RSS feed to find new content
3. repeat site-wide crawl periodically to get updated content

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 'Last-Modified' HTTP header.  In C#, from the HttpWebResponse, if it isn't equal to DateTime.Now, the content has changed.  So, you can use the local content (assuming you are storing it) to feed your crawler.

So, when you crawl, store the WebPage content and the 'Last-Modified' header.

Also, you can either store each unique AbsoluteUri, which works well until the lookup time for the AbsoluteUri eclipses the time needed to fetch the page or you can use a Bloom filter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter.

Other than figuring out where the Google sitemap is (or an RSS feed) you won't know where new content is added.  Automatically knowing is like a burglar asking where your new purchases are without asking you first.  :)